# convert list output to table(object)

Tags: powershell, object

From iperf3 I filtered following output:

```
& $exe -c my_host | Select-Object -Index (2..12)

[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-1.00   sec  11.4 MBytes  95.4 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   1.00-2.00   sec  11.2 MBytes  94.2 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   2.00-3.00   sec  11.2 MBytes  94.3 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   3.00-4.00   sec  11.2 MBytes  94.5 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   4.00-5.00   sec  11.2 MBytes  94.2 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   5.00-6.00   sec  11.2 MBytes  94.4 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   6.00-7.00   sec  11.2 MBytes  94.4 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   7.00-8.00   sec  11.2 MBytes  94.3 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   8.00-9.00   sec  11.2 MBytes  94.2 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   9.00-10.00  sec  11.2 MBytes  94.5 Mbits/sec
```

how can I transform it to table/object in powershell for further processing ?

Comment: There is a cmdlet Format-Table to output result in table. This cmdlet only works on other internal cmdlets, hashtables, psobjects, and other data structures but does not work on external programs. We have to customly output that. There is no cmdlet to directly do that for external programs.

Answer (score 1):

Using this [ConvertFrom-SourceTable](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertFrom-SourceTable):

```
$TextTable = '
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-1.00   sec  11.4 MBytes  95.4 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   1.00-2.00   sec  11.2 MBytes  94.2 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   2.00-3.00   sec  11.2 MBytes  94.3 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   3.00-4.00   sec  11.2 MBytes  94.5 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   4.00-5.00   sec  11.2 MBytes  94.2 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   5.00-6.00   sec  11.2 MBytes  94.4 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   6.00-7.00   sec  11.2 MBytes  94.4 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   7.00-8.00   sec  11.2 MBytes  94.3 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   8.00-9.00   sec  11.2 MBytes  94.2 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   9.00-10.00  sec  11.2 MBytes  94.5 Mbits/sec      
'

$TextTable | ConvertFrom-SourceTable -Literal -Omit '[]'

ID Interval        Transfer    Bandwidth
-- --------        --------    ---------
4  0.00-1.00   sec 11.4 MBytes 95.4 Mbits/sec
4  1.00-2.00   sec 11.2 MBytes 94.2 Mbits/sec
4  2.00-3.00   sec 11.2 MBytes 94.3 Mbits/sec
4  3.00-4.00   sec 11.2 MBytes 94.5 Mbits/sec
4  4.00-5.00   sec 11.2 MBytes 94.2 Mbits/sec
4  5.00-6.00   sec 11.2 MBytes 94.4 Mbits/sec
4  6.00-7.00   sec 11.2 MBytes 94.4 Mbits/sec
4  7.00-8.00   sec 11.2 MBytes 94.3 Mbits/sec
4  8.00-9.00   sec 11.2 MBytes 94.2 Mbits/sec
4  9.00-10.00  sec 11.2 MBytes 94.5 Mbits/sec
```

Comment: I have just added a **new** `-Omit` parameter to the [ConvertFrom-SourceTable](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertFrom-SourceTable) cmdlet which lets you omit certain (special) characters from the header and the data (Each omitted character will be replaced with a space and eventually keys and values will be trimmed). I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you already have a string array as output which results in a Fixed-Width table.

Below I'm using a Here-String to simulate that array

```
$output = @"
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-1.00   sec  11.4 MBytes  95.4 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   1.00-2.00   sec  11.2 MBytes  94.2 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   2.00-3.00   sec  11.2 MBytes  94.3 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   3.00-4.00   sec  11.2 MBytes  94.5 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   4.00-5.00   sec  11.2 MBytes  94.2 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   5.00-6.00   sec  11.2 MBytes  94.4 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   6.00-7.00   sec  11.2 MBytes  94.4 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   7.00-8.00   sec  11.2 MBytes  94.3 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   8.00-9.00   sec  11.2 MBytes  94.2 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   9.00-10.00  sec  11.2 MBytes  94.5 Mbits/sec         
"@ -split '\r?\n'

$result = for ($i = 1; $i -lt $output.Count; $i++) {
    if ($output[$i] -match '^(?<id>.{6})(?<interval>.{19})(?<transfer>.{13})(?<bandwidth>.*)') {
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            'ID' = $matches['id'].Trim('[] ')
            'Interval' = $matches['interval'].Trim()
            'Transfer' = $matches['transfer'].Trim()
            'BandWidth' = $matches['bandwidth'].Trim()
        }
    }
}

# output on screen
$result

#output to CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\table.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Result:

```
ID Interval        Transfer    BandWidth     
-- --------        --------    ---------     
4  0.00-1.00   sec 11.4 MBytes 95.4 Mbits/sec
4  1.00-2.00   sec 11.2 MBytes 94.2 Mbits/sec
4  2.00-3.00   sec 11.2 MBytes 94.3 Mbits/sec
4  3.00-4.00   sec 11.2 MBytes 94.5 Mbits/sec
4  4.00-5.00   sec 11.2 MBytes 94.2 Mbits/sec
4  5.00-6.00   sec 11.2 MBytes 94.4 Mbits/sec
4  6.00-7.00   sec 11.2 MBytes 94.4 Mbits/sec
4  7.00-8.00   sec 11.2 MBytes 94.3 Mbits/sec
4  8.00-9.00   sec 11.2 MBytes 94.2 Mbits/sec
4  9.00-10.00  sec 11.2 MBytes 94.5 Mbits/sec
```