# convert txt file csv with columns

Tags: powershell

so i have a 2 scripts in power shell on is to get the users from the local admin group (that works fine) and another script that is meant to convert the txt file from the first script and export it to csv file. ia am stuck in the end i can't figure out how to do the columns in the csv. i need 2 columns one for computer name and one for members. in the picture is the result that i achieved.
thank you

[image: result]

this is the second script

```
$inputFilePath = "\\path\localaccounts\path.txt"
$outputFilePath = "\\path\localaccounts\path.csv"

$input = Get-Content $inputFilePath | Select-Object -Skip 2
$data = $input[1..($input.Length - 1)]  

$maxLength = 0

$objects = ForEach($record in $data) {
    $split = $record -split "\s{2,}|,"
    If($split.Length -gt $maxLength){
        $maxLength = $split.Length
    }
    $props = @{}
    For($i=0; $i -lt $split.Length; $i++) {
        $props.Add([String]($i+1),$split[$i])

    }
    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $props
}

$headers = [String[]](1..$maxLength)

$objects | 
Select-Object $headers | 
Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $outputFilePath
```

Comment: You may explain what you're actually trying to do - not the way you think you have to go to get what you need ... so a kind of the *big picture*. ;-)  How do you populate the txt file?

Comment: the end result is 2 rows with 2 columns, first row for the computer name and the members headers. the second row is for the nati-desktop user the computername and under members in spearte tabs administrator, nati, domain admins.

Comment: this is the first script:

Comment: invoke-command {
    $members = net localgroup administrators |
     where {($_ -AND $_ -notmatch "command completed successfully")} | select -skip 4
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
     Computername = $env:COMPUTERNAME
     Group = "Administrators"
     Members=$members -join "," 
     } 
    }  -computer $env:COMPUTERNAME -HideComputerName | 
    Select computername,members -ExcludeProperty RunspaceID | out-file -filepath \\eproc-srv\localaccounts\$env:COMPUTERNAME.txt

Comment: I'm not understanding what you want the output to look like? Do you want a "computername" column with the computername, a "group" column, "users", etc?

Comment: Please DO NOT add additional information as commnets. Instead edit your question and update it with all needed information.

Comment: Regardless of that - why don't you use `Export-Csv` to create a proper CSV file in your first script??  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Please add an exaple of the input data to your question. As a possible solution, you might check this question: [convert list output to table(object)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60881160/1701026). As an aside: don't use the [automatic `$Input` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables#input)

Comment: the answer gives me an idea of what to do, it wasent perfect but with minor changes it works for me. anyway i removed the accepted answer because you were right somebody will confused.

Comment: Thanks, @nati. Your question is still somewhat underspecified, so I encourage you to (a) update your question to fully describe your intent, including sample output,  and (b) post your own answer with a matching solution. That said, Olaf's answer looks like a much better solution; all it needs is the addition of an `Export-Csv` call (and, possibly, renaming of the output columns / removal of the `ObjectClass` column).

Answer (score 1):

To make your life much easier you should collect the data you're after with native PowerShell cmdlets in the first place. This way you don't need to deal with string acrobatics later on.

Something like this should be enough actually. At least it could be a starting point for further steps

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'RemoteComputerName' -ScriptBlock {
    Get-LocalGroupMember -Group administrators
    } |
        Select-Object -Property PSComputerName, Name, ObjectClass
```

Regardless of that: You should not add DomainAdmins to any local administrators group!

Answer (score -1):

I made some changes to your script

````
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sf9R.png)```
$inputFilePath = "\\path\localaccounts\path.txt"
$outputFilePath = "\\path\localaccounts\path.csv"

$input = Get-Content $inputFilePath | Select-Object -Skip 2
$data = $input[1..($input.Length - 1)]  

$maxLength = 0
$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
ForEach($record in $data) 
{
    $split = $record -split "\s{2,}|,"
    If($split.Length -gt $maxLength){
        $maxLength = $split.Length
    }
    $newRow = New-Object -TypeName psobject
   
    For($i=0; $i -lt $split.Length; $i++) {
        $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Col$i -NotePropertyValue $split[$i];
    }
    $table.Add($newRow) | Out-Null
}

$table

$table | 
Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $outputFilePath
````

Comment: I'm mystified that @nati accepted this answer, given that it is just a slower, less robust, and less PowerShell-idiomatic reformulation of the code that is already in the question (with the incidental variation of changing the column names).

Comment: @mklement0 : The OP said his code did not separate the columns!!!

Comment: No, the OP said that they want _two_ columns, and even showed the results of their own one-column-per-member solution (like yours) in a screenshot (originally obscured by broken formatting - which you copied verbatim to your answer ). If you had analyzed the OP's code, you would have realized that your code doesn't offer anything substantially different - only something that is slower, makes an unsolicited incidental change, and - unlike the OP's code - malfunctions with multiple objects if the first one happens to contain fewer members than later ones.

Comment: @mklement0 : Then why did OP give me credit for my solution?

Comment: In their own words: "the answer gives me an idea of what to do, it wasent perfect but with minor changes it works for me. anyway i removed the accepted answer because you were right somebody will confused." Given my analysis of your answer it isn't clear to me _what_ idea your answer may have inspired, and I suspect it won't be clear to others either. So I think it's for the better that your answer was un-accepted, especially since it is nothing but an inferior reformulation of the code in the question.