# Read csv file having null values in some fields and also doesn't have the exact the same format values?

Tags: powershell, csv

I have csv file (ABC.CSV) which is having data in below format

```
COLUMN1 COLUMN2 COLUMN3      COLUMN4     COLUMN5
12345   ABC     RR,MM K      NAO,KUM      DEV
34567   CDEF    NN                        INT
89567   KGH     PP, BHIM     PRKC         PROD
9876    PIM                               DEV          
6543    KCDEF   NICE,MAN K                INT  
5432    GHK                  SIN,NICE C   PROD
```

Below is the powershell code which I am using to read this csv file

```
$filePath = "C:\path\to\your\abc.csv"
$searchString = "9876"

# Read the content of the file
$content = Get-Content -Path $filePath

# Process each line of the file
foreach ($line in $content) {
    # Split the line into individual values
    $values = $line -split ','

    # Extract the values
    $column1 = $values[0].Trim()
    $column2 = $values[1].Trim()
    $column3 = ($values[2].Trim('"'), $values[3].Trim('"')) -join ','
    $column4 = $values[4].Trim()
    $column5 = $values[5].Trim()
    
    if ($column1 -like "9876" -and $column5 -like "PROD" {
     Write-Host $column1
     Write-Host $column2
     Write-Host $column3
     Write-Host $column4
     Write-Host $column5

    }
```

This code is working only when all fields are in correct shape but any filed is null or COLUMN 4 & 5 is having value just CC not CC, KK then it is throwing the error.

FINE FOR THIS VALUE

```
12345   ABC     RR,MM K      NAO,KUM      DEV
```

NOT SHOWING CORRECT RESULTS FOR SUCH VALUES

```
    34567   CDEF    NN                        INT
    89567   KGH     PP, BHIM     PRKC         PROD
    9876    PIM                               DEV          
    6543    KCDEF   NICE,MAN K                INT  
    5432    GHK                  SIN,NICE C   PROD
```

Comment: That's not a CSV file. CSV means *Comma Separated Values*. If you were actually parsing a CSV file, you wouldn't be having these issues. The file extension is meaningless - you can give a plain text file a .JPG extension, but that doesn't mean it actually holds an image.

Comment: Its worth checking to see if its a Tab Delimited File, try `Import-Csv -Delimiter "\`t" -Path $filePath`

Comment: As a general solution you might try this [`ConvertFrom-SourceTable`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertFrom-SourceTable), see also: [convert list output to table(object)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60882963/1701026)

Answer (score 1):

As has been noted, **your data *isn't* in [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) format**, but seemingly in the form of ***fixed-width columns***, whose boundaries are implied by the character positions where the *column names* start.

**The following transforms your file into CSV format and parses the result into *objects* using [`ConvertTo-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/ConvertTo-Csv)** - note that the **solution works *generically*** based on the assumptions above; it neither relies on a *specific number of columns* nor on their *specific lengths*:

```bash
# Read the file into the header line and all data lines.
$headerLine, $dataLines = Get-Content $filePath

# Get the indices of the characters that end the fields.
# + -1 adds an extra array element that is a placeholder for the end of the line.
$fieldEndIndices = [regex]::Matches($headerLine, ' \S').Index + -1

# Iterate over all data lines.
$objects =
  $dataLines |  
  ForEach-Object {
    # Split the line at hand into fields, trim each field and enclose it in "..."
    $pos = 0
    $fields = 
      foreach ($fieldEndIndex in $fieldEndIndices) {
        if ($fieldEndIndex -eq -1) { $fieldEndIndex = $_.Length - 1 } 
        '"' + $_.Substring($pos, $fieldEndIndex - $pos + 1).Trim() + '"'
        $pos += $fieldEndIndex - $pos + 1
      }
    # Output the fields as a CSV line
    $fields -join ','
  } |
  ConvertFrom-Csv -Header (-split $headerLine) # Parse the CSV data into objects.
```

After running the above, `$objects` contains an array of [`[pscustomobject]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_PSCustomObject) instances whose properties are named for the columns in the input data and whose values are the field values.

To visualize the results, you can run `$objects | Format-Table`, which yields the following, showing that the data was parsed as intended:

```
COLUMN1 COLUMN2 COLUMN3    COLUMN4    COLUMN5
------- ------- -------    -------    -------
12345   ABC     RR,MM K    NAO,KUM    DEV
34567   CDEF    NN                    INT
89567   KGH     PP, BHIM   PRKC       PROD
9876    PIM                           DEV
6543    KCDEF   NICE,MAN K            INT
5432    GHK                SIN,NICE C PROD
```

Answer (score 0):

You have fixed with data, not CSV.  Try regex below which uses hardcoded column widths :

```
$filename = 'c:\temp\test.csv'
$pattern = '(?<column1>.{8})(?<column2>.{8})(?<column3>.{13})(?<column4>.{11})(?<column5>.*)'
$data = Get-Content -Path $filename | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Select-String -Pattern $pattern
$table = $data | foreach {[PSCustomObject]@{
   column1 = $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value.Trim() 
   column2 = $_.Matches.Groups[2].Value.Trim()
   column3 = $_.Matches.Groups[3].Value.Trim()
   column4 = $_.Matches.Groups[4].Value.Trim()
   column5 = $_.Matches.Groups[5].Value.Trim()
} }
$table | Format-Table
```

Results

```
column1 column2 column3    column4    column5
------- ------- -------    -------    -------
12345   ABC     RR,MM K    NAO,KUM    DEV
34567   CDEF    NN                    INT
89567   KGH     PP, BHIM   PRKC       PROD
9876    PIM                           DEV
6543    KCDEF   NICE,MAN K            INT
5432    GHK                SIN,NICE C PROD
```

Comment: To clarify: this solution (a) assumes a _fixed number of columns_ and (b) _hard-codes the specific column widths_. I suggest making these clarifications part of your answer, given that many users don't pay attention to comments.